# Model validation failed (#/EventSourceArn: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern])

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In AWS cloud formation,
I am facing below validation error:

```
Model validation failed (#/EventSourceArn: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern])
```

**canary.yaml**

```
Canary:
    Type: AWS::Synthetics::Canary
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: test12345678901234567889-development
      Code:
        Handler: exports.handler
        Script: |
          const https = require('https')
          const URL = process.env.URL;
          var synthetics = require('Synthetics');
          const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
          log.info('URL:'+URL);
          exports.handler = async function(event) {
            const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              https.get(URL, (res) => {
                  resolve(res.statusCode)
                }).on('error', (e) => {
                  reject(Error(e))
                })
              })
            return promise
          }
      ExecutionRoleArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - CloudWatchSyntheticsRole
          - Arn
      RuntimeVersion: syn-nodejs-puppeteer-3.2
      RunConfig:
        TimeoutInSeconds: 60
        EnvironmentVariables:
          URL : !Sub "http://{{resolve:ssm:/${Portfolio}/${ApplicationEnvironmentTag}/common/ApplicationLoadBalancerUrl}}/management/health"
      ArtifactS3Location:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - s3://
            - Ref: ResultsBucket
      StartCanaryAfterCreation: True
      Schedule:
        Expression: rate(1 minute) # every minute
        DurationInSeconds: 0 # run indefinitely
      SuccessRetentionPeriod: 90
      FailureRetentionPeriod: 180
```

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-resource-schema/issues/127

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue

The issue is about canary name pattern & validation.

**The name must be a maximum of 21 characters. Mine was greater than that.**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-synthetics-canary.html#cfn-synthetics-canary-name

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I found the issue aswell on my end.

**The name contained uppercase letters.**

I don't want to steal the answer, but maybe it helps others. I was aware of the 21 character limit and couldn't see it.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this entry because I was looking for help regarding a similar case: I tried to create a Web Application Firewall (Waf) and got the error

> Model validation failed (#/Description: failed validation constraint
> for keyword [pattern])

with no further explanation.

With the comments I read here I understood where to look and found out that my description contained `(` and `)` which didn't follow the [allowed pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-description).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the allowed regex. Turns out I was using `_` instead of `-` in my S3 bucket names, and that was not part of the regex. For reference, the linked regex is `^[a-zA-Z0-9=:#@/\-,.][a-zA-Z0-9+=:#@/\-,.\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9+=:#@/\-,.]{1,256}$`